# Image size issue in Liferay 6.2 document and media portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm facing an issue in document and media portlet liferay 6.2 since a long time. There are two scenarios -

1) I upload an image of 2MB and when I download it's size increases to 3.2MB.

2) I upload an image of 5MB and when I download it's size decreases to 500KB.

For some images, it works fine but for some images it doesn't. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Without the images, download URL used and exact Liferay version, there's not much to help you with

Comment: ...and on top, this is not programming related, thus not a good fit for stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - I'd suggest you delete the question here and come over to the Liferay forums (with the additional information).

Comment: Thanks. Posted over liferay forum.